# Jenkins declarative pipeline - set environment variables in methods

Tags: java, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins Pipeline Code which is too long. If i try to build it, the output is “method code too large”.. this happens because the method bytecode cant be no larger than 64kb.. my code exists of many  environment variable declarations and some small build steps.. i can put the build steps into methods to enlarge the "main"method but that doesnt do much.. is there a way to set environment variables in methods?

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
General error during class generation: Method code too large!

java.lang.RuntimeException: Method code too large!
```

Comment: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-37984

Comment: The question is not really clear - what is the relation of your code with 'environment variables'? it seems as 2 different issues! Can you put part of your code in the question?

Comment: its only one question,method code is too large is just a fact and the answer is to break down the code into several methods. Methods can only be included into declarative pipeline script in the "steps" section but environment variables are set in the stage section which doesnt allow to include methods.
the question is, is there a way to do smth like that(that doesnt work as shown:
pipeline{
 agent any
 stages{
  stage{
   environment{
    temporaryEnvVars()
   }
   steps{
   }
  }
 }
}
def temporaryEnvVars(){
 Path = "C:/blabla"
 Version = "2.0.1"
 .
 .
 .
}